# A module of Python-2.7 not getting imported when it is definitely installed

Tags: python, python-2.7

My pandas package is not getting imported.
When I try to check if I have pandas using the command

```
python -c "import pandas"
```

It shows some strange error like

```
<module 'numpy' from 'numpy.pyc'>
'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in   <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable    (pandas/hashtable.c:21706)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Have you tried `import numpy` above it?

Comment: Glad to see you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *local* file named `numpy.py` which is being imported instead of the globally installed NumPy project:

```
<module 'numpy' from 'numpy.pyc'>
```

Remove or rename that file and delete the associated `numpy.pyc` file next to it. Your local file has no name `dtype`, only the `numpy` *package* installed in your `site-packages` does, but it can't be loaded when your file is found first every time.